# Trying to get the text value of a field that has been updated by a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(JS Fiddle full code is below)

I am selecting a value from a dropdown which then based on selection will update the next table 'td' with a value.
I am then looping through the table 'tr' to get a ";" separated list of all the values

In my fiddle example, I have simplified it to 2 columns where if you select "1" from the dropdown, the next field is updated with 10 and then the next row, the same

My goal is to get a list of the values in the table

```
For Example 1;10
            2;8
```

For some reason, I am looping through the table: "Get Data Button initiates loop")

```
$(this).find("td").filter(':visible').each(function (index) {
            if (index === 1) {
                if ($(this).find("span").val() != undefined) {
                    values += $(this).find("span").val() + ";";
                }
                if ($(this).find("text").val() != undefined) {
                    values += $(this).find("text").val() + ";";
                }
                if ($(this).find("label").text() != undefined) {
                    values += $(this).find("label").text() + ";";
                }

                if ($(this).find("select option:selected").text() != "") {
                    values += $(this).find("select option:selected").text() + ";";
                }
            }
        });
```

But whether I use .text(), val(), inner or outerHTML it is always ""

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/motti10/hjdyxv7n/4/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what the purpose is, but I have the output wanted with this solution:

```
       if (index === 0) 
       {
            if ($(this).find("span").val()) {
                values += $(this).find("span").val() + ";";
       ....
```

updated the fiddle as well http://jsfiddle.net/hjdyxv7n/5/

Comment: Axel,I am not trying to get the values from the dropdowns, but the values under header ROW2
Select 1 from dropdown and it sets ROW2 to "10"
I am trying to log out "10"

The purpose is to take the values and update my database